# Group by and sum across column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am using this dataframe:

```
                                Col1   Col2  Col3     Date
Name                  Score                                            
Bob                     0       True  False   False   15/05/2020  
Alice                   5       True  False   False   15/05/2020             
John                    0       True  False   False   15/05/2020   
Bob                    10       True  False   False   16/05/2020    
Chris                   0       True  False   False   16/05/2020   
Alice                   2       True  False   False   17/05/2020
```

....

I would need to aggregate this by `Name` and then by `Score` to get the `Score` per `Name`, to see which name has the highest score, then the others. Also I would like to get the `Score` by `Name` by `Date`.

My expected output should be:

```
                                    Date
Name                  Score                                            
Bob                     0        15/05/2020  
Alice                   5        15/05/2020             
John                    0        15/05/2020   
Bob                    10        16/05/2020    
Chris                   0        16/05/2020   
Alice                   2        17/05/2020

  Date            Name    Score
15/05/2020         Alice   5
                   Bob     0 
                   John    0       # preferably in desc order
16/05/2020         Bob     10
                   Chris   0
17/05/2020         Alice   2
```

And also

```
Name      Score
Bob         10
Alice       7
John        0
Chris       0
```

I have tried to use

```
df.groupby(['Name','Score']).sum())
df.groupby(['Name','Date','Score']).sum())
```

But I am not sure this is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You want to group on `Name` and sum the `score` for respective names:

```
In [907]: df = df.reset_index()
In [909]: res = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)['Score'].sum()
In [920]: res.sort_values('Score', ascending=False)
Out[920]: 
    Name  Score
1    Bob     10
0  Alice      7
2  Chris      0
3   John      0
```

2) You want to group on `name` and `Date` and sum the `score` for respective names:

```
In [910]: df.groupby(['Date','Name'])['Score'].sum()
Out[910]: 
Date        Name 
15/05/2020  Alice     5
            Bob       0
            John      0
16/05/2020  Bob      10
            Chris     0
17/05/2020  Alice     2
Name: Score, dtype: int64
```